# Yahoo Pandas datareader date difference

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I am trying to import stock data using Yahoo API as a source. I have tried it many times and I always get the same error, the start and end date are different from what I have passed. For example I pass the start and end date as **'2015-1-1' & '2017-1-1'** but the stock data I get start and ends at **'2014-12-31' & '2016-12-30'**. I dont know what I am doing wrong. I even tried using google but got a error as "data_sorce='google' not implemented."
Is there some other free data source I can use or correct the dates while using Yahoo?  [Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt8hF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import as [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) and just enter a start and end when importing the data. Yahoo decommissioned their historical data API check out the Ran Aroussi the developer's of fix-yahoo-finance which is now yfinance blog where he details everything nicely https://aroussi.com/post/python-yahoo-finance

**To install/upgrade yfinance using pip, run:**

```
$ pip install yfinance
```

instead of this method

```
facebook = web.DateReader("FB", "yahoo", start, end)
```

**can be in a format like this instead**

**override method from pandas_datareader by importing data as pdr**

```
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== the override :-)

# download dataframe using pandas_datareader
facebook = pdr.get_data_yahoo("FB", start="2015-1-1", end="2017-1-1")
```

**or you can just use yfinance instead**

```
import yfinance as yf
facebook = yf.download("FB", start="2015-1-1", end="2017-1-1")
```

[image: jupyter notebook]